# Keep d3 map inside div when zooming

Tags: css, d3.js

I've a SVG map rendered with d3 and I've inserted a function to zoom that works. But when I do it the map goes over the others elements of the page. Basically, I would like to would like to keep the map inside the its div container (in the case below the one with class "col-sm-10").

My HTML code

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
<div id="map">
</div>
</div>
```

D3JS

```
var svg = d3.select("#map")
.append("svg")
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
.attr("viewBox", "0 0 900 500")
.classed("svg-content-responsive", true)
.call(d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([1, 8])
.on("zoom", function () {
svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)    
}))
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you zoom map map size increases and map overflows from your container so you can hide overflow content by `overflow: hidden;` property to map container like this
**CSS:**

```
.map-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-10 map-container">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</div>
```